# The verb "manage" is confusing

Tags: verbs

> A:  That's a very difficult job.
>
> B: I'll **manage** / **manage to do** it

Is simply **manage** the same as **manage to do?**

In the sentence:

> **Manage** your Google account.

What is the meaning of **manage?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not the same. There are two very different uses.

To ‘manage to do something’ means that you do it, but it implies that it’s quite difficult to do, and takes a lot of effort.

However, to ‘manage something’ is to make sure it works how you want it to work; managing your Google account means making sure it’s on the right privacy setting, Google only has access to the contact details you want them to, etc.

As you can see, there are two different ways to use the verb ‘manage’. No one definition fits the whole, but two together build a picture of all the ways it can be used. Hope that helps!